# Sitecore: inject dependency into sitecore components

Tags: dependency-injection, sitecore

I'm using Sitecore 8.1 MVC with Autofac as the DI. I was wondering what is the recommended way to injecting resolved objects into sitecore created objects i.e. pipelines, commands, computed fields etc... As an example, i am using a membership provider in which i need to invoke my business layer. Is it possible for me to define a constructor on the class and sitecore would injects the objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With things like pipeline processors, commands etc... Basically anything that Sitecore creates - you are fairly limited. The normal approach is to use the Service Locator pattern to resolve dependencies:

```
var membershipProvider = DependencyResolver.Current.Resolve<IMembershipProvider>()
```

There are other ways tho. This post: https://cardinalcore.co.uk/2014/07/02/sitecore-pipelines-commands-using-ioc-containers/ uses a container factory class to resolve the dependencies in the pipeline. This is the class used:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis;

using Sitecore.Reflection;

public class ContainerFactory : IFactory
{
    private readonly IContainerManager containerManager;

    public ContainerFactory() : this(new LocatorContainerManager()) // service locate an appropriate container
    {
    }

    public ContainerFactory(IContainerManager containerManager)
    {
        this.containerManager = containerManager;
    }

    public object GetObject(string identifier)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(identifier);
        return this.containerManager.Resolve(type);
    }
}
```

Then this would be setup as the factory for the event or processor using the `factory` attribute in the config. Example config:

```
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="item:saved">
      <handler factory="ContainerFactory" ref="MyApp.MyHandler, MyApp" method="MyMethod">
        <database>master</database>
      </handler>
    </event>
  </events>
  <pipelines>
    <MyPipeline>
      <processor type="1" factory="ContainerFactory" ref="MyApp.MyProcessor, MyApp" />
    </MyPipeline>
  </pipelines>
  <factories>
    <factory id="ContainerFactory" type="MyApp.ContainerFactory"></factory>
  </factories>
</sitecore>
```

With this second method, you can inject your dependencies in your constructor as you normally would.

These are probably the 2 most commonly used options.

Comment: Just be careful with service locator and captive dependencies. You will want to perform a release within a `try/finally`